# Running junit ant-task without build.xml

Tags: java, deployment, ant, jar, junit

I'm trying to work out how I can run an ant task without actually needed a build.xml.
In particular I want to run a `JUnit` task with a formatter. In xml format this looks like below:

```
<junit printsummary="true" errorProperty="test.failed" failureProperty="test.failed">
    <classpath refid="run.class.path" />

    <!-- console log -->
    <formatter type="xml" classname="be.x.SFFormatter" />

    <test name="be.x.SF" outfile="result" todir="${build.output.dir}" />
</junit>
```

It works when running the ant script, but I would like to get my app running as a runnable jar.
Running the tests from Java was easy:

```
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    testResult = junit.run(SeleniumFramework.class);
```

However, I struggle to work out how to actually get the formatter to work.
The formatter is of type `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter` so I doubt I can just plug it in somewhere without running ant.

Has anyone done something similar before?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant doesn't do any magic. All it does is read the XML file, create the beans specified in it and then execute the methods as per the Task API (`org.apache.tools.ant.Task`).

So all you need is to do the same in your code. Don't forget to create a `Project` :-)

Comment: I've decided to just bundle the build file into my jar and run it internally. A bit sad it makes my end product depend on ant now, but for the moment I can live with it

Answer (score 1):

You may use Ant via Groovy to avoid the xml syntax.
See => [Using Ant from Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy) for details.